# C2504 'MainClass':base class undefined

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement state design pattern but i keep getting base class undefined error. These are my files.
**MainClass.h**

```
#pragma once


#include "State1.h"
#include "State.h"

class State;
class MainClass
{
public:
    MainClass();
    ~MainCLass();
    void changeState(AuctionState* newState);
private:
    State *CurrentState;

};
```

**In my MainClass.cpp class, the changestate method is**

```
 void MainClass::changeState(State * newState)
    {
        delete CurrentState;
        CurrentState = newState;
    }
```

**State.h**

```
    #pragma once    

#include "MainClass.h"
class MainClass;
class AuctionState
{
public:
    virtual ~AuctionState();
    virtual void run(MainClass& context);
};
```

**State1.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "State2.h"
#include "State.h"
class State2;
class MainState :
    public AuctionState
{
public:
    MainState();
    ~MainState();
};
```

**State1.cpp**

```
#include "State1.h"



MainState::MainState()
{

}
void run(MainClass& context)
{

            //DO Stuff


            context.changeState(new State2);


}

MainState::~MainState()
{
}
```

All the other state files are implemented the same way

Comment: You don't need a full include if you are just going to forward-declare a class. You currently have circular dependencies because of that.

Comment: Then i get a "left of method must have clss/struct/union

Comment: You still need the includes, but in the cpp files. The h files only need forward declarations.